# How to generate breadcrumbs when I have a following category structure

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a following nested categories structure array and now I need to generate breadcrumbs for each category. Suppose I am currently viewing the Adidas category page which is in **Brands->Apparel->Adidas** so I need breadcrumbs like this **Brands/Apparel/Adidas**.

Categories array structure follows:

```
[1] => Array
(
    [name] => 01e3f447-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
    [nodeInfo] => stdClass Object
        (
            [idCategory] => 01e3f447-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
            [category] => Brands
            [slug] => brands
            [description] => 
            [image] => 
            [parentCategory] => 
            [idStatus] => e9d3b949-1301-11e7-a9b8-b8763f541038
            [date] => 2017-06-07 14:58:31
        )

    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 0ded5b28-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                    [nodeInfo] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [idCategory] => 0ded5b28-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                            [category] => Apparel
                            [slug] => apparel
                            [description] => 
                            [image] => 
                            [parentCategory] => 01e3f447-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                            [idStatus] => e9d3b949-1301-11e7-a9b8-b8763f541038
                            [date] => 2017-06-07 14:58:51
                        )

                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => 3681265e-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                    [nodeInfo] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [idCategory] => 3681265e-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                            [category] => Adidas
                                            [slug] => adidas
                                            [description] => 
                                            [image] => 
                                            [parentCategory] => 0ded5b28-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                            [idStatus] => e9d3b949-1301-11e7-a9b8-b8763f541038
                                            [date] => 2017-06-07 14:59:59
                                        )

                                    [children] => 
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => 3f211015-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                    [nodeInfo] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [idCategory] => 3f211015-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                            [category] => Columbia
                                            [slug] => columbia
                                            [description] => 
                                            [image] => 
                                            [parentCategory] => 0ded5b28-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                            [idStatus] => e9d3b949-1301-11e7-a9b8-b8763f541038
                                            [date] => 2017-06-07 15:00:14
                                        )

                                    [children] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 1988d10a-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                    [nodeInfo] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [idCategory] => 1988d10a-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                            [category] => Footwear
                            [slug] => footwear
                            [description] => 
                            [image] => 
                            [parentCategory] => 01e3f447-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                            [idStatus] => e9d3b949-1301-11e7-a9b8-b8763f541038
                            [date] => 2017-06-07 14:59:11
                        )

                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => 49becbc8-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                    [nodeInfo] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [idCategory] => 49becbc8-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                            [category] => Polo
                                            [slug] => polo
                                            [description] => 
                                            [image] => 
                                            [parentCategory] => 1988d10a-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                            [idStatus] => e9d3b949-1301-11e7-a9b8-b8763f541038
                                            [date] => 2017-06-07 15:00:31
                                        )

                                    [children] => 
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => 4e647bee-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                    [nodeInfo] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [idCategory] => 4e647bee-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                            [category] => Nike
                                            [slug] => nike
                                            [description] => 
                                            [image] => 
                                            [parentCategory] => 1988d10a-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                            [idStatus] => e9d3b949-1301-11e7-a9b8-b8763f541038
                                            [date] => 2017-06-07 15:00:39
                                        )

                                    [children] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I mean, you just need the slug of each array, right?

Comment: I need breadcrumb array from child category adidas which i am currently viewing to the top level category brands.